# New born Baby cries a lot

Tags: newborn

My baby is 2 weeks old and cries a lot sudden, his grandma think it's because of tummy as he get pain in tummy and have they have started to give him drops of Liquorice extract water on a room temperature (which IMO is strange), how to know what is going on with my baby? As I hate grandma experiments on her.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! Have you taken him to a doctor to ask about it? I don't think tea is a good idea for a newborn, either :)

Comment: @Erica no I haven't. Midwife is due tomorrow so I might check. Well stupid myth of old people makes me angry too. But just wondering what can be reason.

Comment: @Erica correction, it was Liquorice extract water like booking it up in water.

Comment: A great checklist for crying baby can be found here: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/why-is-my-newborn-crying-constantly/2925#2925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babies cry when they 1) are hungry, 2) need a new diaper, 3) are sick, 4) feel like crying.

If the three first conditions have been checked, your baby is "just crying". It happens a lot. No worries. It's been encoded in our genes, it's a retrieval signal sent from baby to mother when mother left the baby alone in the old savannah to fetch some food.

Comment: If only this list was complete - 5) are lonely or afraid 6) are tired 7) are overwhelmed by new impressions ....and I suppose if we think hard we will come up with a few more points.

Comment: There is also "in pain" or "sick".... While most crying is quite normal and mundane, how does a parent know (a new one especially!) when it's time to be worried about crying?